# Understanding exponential computation by digit recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, arithmetic, floating-point

I've met in a book the following algorithm that computes the exponential:

Input: $t, n$ ($n$ is the number of steps)

Output: $E_n$

$\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{define $t_0 = 0$ ; $E_0 = 1$} \\
\mbox{build two sequences $t_i$ and $E_i$ as follows} \\
t_{n+1} = t_n + ln(1 + d_n 2^{-n}) \\
E_{n+1} = E_n(1 + d_n 2^{-n}) \\
d_n = \begin{cases}
      1 & \mbox{if $t_n + ln(1 + 2^{-n}) \leq t$} \\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
\end{array}$

It is taken from [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817643720). My question is not theoretical (it resembles the restoring division, or square root, or reciprocal) but implementative. To me it looks like that such algorithm requires a LUT that stores the values of $ln(1 + 2^{-n})$ while the others algorithms i mentioned don't... 
Does the algorithm actually requires a LUT to be implemented? or could be somehow exploited the fact that $ln(1 + 2^{-n}) \approx 2^{-n}$?